# Intersection of reciprocal (of) linear space with linear function

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods

Given matrices $\mathbf{A}, \mathbf{B} \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ for $m \geq n$, I want to find $\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ satisfying

$\mathbf{A}\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{y}$

$z_i = 1/y_i \; \forall \, i\in\left\{1,\ldots,m\right\} $

$\mathbf{z}^T\mathbf{B} = \mathbf{1}$

Another interpretation of this problem is finding the intersection of the "element-wise reciprocal" of the column space of $\mathbf{A}$ with the linear function defined (implicitly) by $\mathbf{z}^T\mathbf{B} = \mathbf{1}$.

Is there a straightforward (numerical) approach to solve this system? Thanks in advance for your help.